# Close ServerSocket

Tags: java, sockets

i created GUI server when press on start button open socket , when press close button call close method for that socket.when start server i can connect to it using telnet for testing,when press stop button telnet still connected to my server.When close my GUI server window , telnet is released.how can i release all clients connected to my server after press close button only ? thnx

Comment: Oh my man. What have you been smoking?

Answer (score 1):

You have to close all existing connections, too. Only closing the server socket will not terminate existing connections.

Comment: i only open one serversocket , there is no any existing connections

Comment: Then what does your telnet client do? Smoke signals? (Hint: it’s a connection. To the `Socket` that drops out of `ServerSocket.accept()`.)

Comment: Ok..how can i close this connection.i mean Socket that drops out of ServerSocket.accept()

Comment: Just close the socket, or close its input- and/or output stream.